# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never' --> React with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, properties, fetch, typescript-never

I get a warning (see picture) and I have tried everything to fix it. I understand a map or filter can't exist on 'never' but with the 'fetchAPI?' question mark should in my mind fix the problem. Any suggestions?

See pictures!

[The useState const](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akIu2.png)
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2yrn.png)

I have tried:

```
 const [fetchAPI, setFetchAPI] = useState('')
 const [fetchAPI, setFetchAPI] = useState([])
 const [fetchAPI, setFetchAPI] = useState()
 const [fetchAPI, setFetchAPI] = useState(null)
 const [fetchAPI, setFetchAPI] = useState('' || [] || null)
```

None of those work:))